# Out of memory in a thread pool in C, Linux

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, out-of-memory, threadpool

I need to create infinite loop and with a thread pool create for example 200 threads to do the job from infinite loop.

I'm using this thread pool - https://github.com/Pithikos/C-Thread-Pool

In the same time I'm monitoring the server resources (with htop) and see that memory is increasing on 3 megabytes every second until the kernel kills the application.

The code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <pthread.h>
#include "thpool.h"


#define MAX_IPv4 256


/* Args for thread start function */
typedef struct {
    int octet1;
    int octet2;
    int octet3;
    int octet4;
} args_struct;

/* Thread task */
void task1(void *args) {

    args_struct *actual_args = args;

    printf("%d.%d.%d.%d\n", actual_args->octet1, actual_args->octet2, actual_args->octet3, actual_args->octet4);

    /* Do some job */
    sleep(1);   

    /* Free the args */
    free(args);
}


/* Main function */
int main( void ) {

    int i=0, j=0, n=0, m=0;

    /* Making threadpool n threads */
    threadpool thpool = thpool_init(200);

    /* Infinite loop start from the certain ip*/
    while (1) {
        for (i=0; i < MAX_IPv4; ++i) {
            for (j=0; j < MAX_IPv4; ++j) {
                for (n=0; n < MAX_IPv4; ++n) {
                    for (m=0; m < MAX_IPv4; ++m) {

                            /* Heap memory for the args different for the every thread */
                            args_struct *args = malloc(sizeof *args);
                            args->octet1 = i;
                            args->octet2 = j;
                            args->octet3 = n;
                            args->octet4 = m;

                            /* Create thread */
                            thpool_add_work(thpool, (void*)task1, (void*)args);
                    }
                }
            }
        }

        /* Start from 0.0.0.0 */
        i=0; 
        j=0; 
        n=0; 
        m=0;
    }

    /* Wait until the all threads are done */
    thpool_wait(thpool);

    /* Destroy the threadpool */
    thpool_destroy(thpool);

    return 0;
}
```

How to solve this issue?

Comment: why uses 4 `for` loops? You case is exactly like looping from 0 to `UINT_MAX` and split the 4 bytes to get 4 octets. Another problem is you're allocating 64GB of memory (`(sizeof *args)*UINT_MAX`). Do you have enough memory and compiling a 64-bit program? Moreover allocating 4 billion times is much less efficient than allocating all at once

Comment: you're also creating more than 4 billion threads and probably the system will go out of PID

Comment: Lưu Vĩnh Phúc, thanks for the answer, you are right, so what is the proper solution?

Comment: either use a counter to limit the number of task in the queue, or submit a bug report to the thread pool lib to use a ring buffer

Comment: dvhh, could you send some links on how to do this? Maybe other threadpool lib will work better?

Comment: Lưu Vĩnh Phúc, I have only 8GB of memory

Comment: Your strategy is just completely flawed. You should at least put `thpool_wait` inside the `while(1)` loop. Only restart the cascade when all threads have finished. Otherwise you just go on and on until your system crashes. From the first second your process will be so heavily managing threads that even those threads that run will never be able to do much.

Comment: try reading this http://www.yolinux.com/TUTORIALS/LinuxTutorialPosixThreads.html , more about the mutexes there is an exemple with counter, either use a loop to check before adding new jobs or use signal

Comment: there is also a suggestion to check the queue length with `thpool.jobqueue.len`, which could avoid the use of counter

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Looking at issues for your library ( especially [this one](https://github.com/Pithikos/C-Thread-Pool/issues/20) about memory consumption ).

There is a recommendation to check the job queue length `threadpool.jobqueue.len`;

Maybe your code could check after adding your job to the queue

Unfortunately the `threadpool` is an opaque pointer and you could not access the value directly.

I would recommend adding a function for the threadpool in `thpool.c` :

```
int thpool_jobqueue_length(thpool_* thpool_p) {
    return thpool->jobqueue->len;
}
```

And don't forget the declaration in `thpool.h`

```
int thpool_jobqueue_length(threadpool);
```

Then modify your code

```
const int SOME_ARBITRARY_VALUE = 400
...
thpool_add_work(thpool, (void*)task1, (void*)args);
while( ( thpool_jobqueue_length(thpool) > SOME_ARBITRARY_VALUE ) ) {
    sleep(1);
}
...
```

Comment: Thanks a lot, but there is an error: request for member ‘jobqueue’ in something not a structure or union

Comment: the variable `thpool` is a pointer, which I missed, I amended the solution to `thpool->jobqueue->len`

Comment: I tried this, but have an error too: error: dereferencing pointer to incomplete type 
        while( ( thpool->jobqueue->len > SOME_ARBITRARY_VALUE ) ) {

Comment: Foiled by opaque pointers,  move the structure definition from `thpool.c` to `thpool.h` or add a function to return the number of queued job in `thpool.c`

Comment: I added some instruction on how to modify the files

Comment: It works, thanks a lot! Here is the correct solution: while( ( thpool->jobqueue_p->len > SOME_ARBITRARY_VALUE ) ) { .. and move the structure definition from thpool.c to thpool.h

Answer (score 1):

Looking at the code for `thpool_add_work` there is some memory use per call (allocating a job record to add to a queue), so as your loop runs forever, it is not surprising that it will run out of memory at some point. You are also allocating memory inside your innermost loop, so that too will help use up all your memory.

Essentially inside your inner loop you are allocating 16 bytes (assuming int is 4) for the `args_struct`, and `thpool_add_work` is also allocating 12 bytes (possibly rounded to 16 for alignment purposes).

As you can imagine, that adds up to a lot for your 4 nested loops (which are also run infinitely).

Comment: Thanks for the answer, everything became clear, but what is a solution to this issue?